# What type, name of a multidimensional array is?

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am trying to grasp the concept of pointers in multidiensional arrays and there are some things I would like to clarify. Let's have a small 2-D array B for an example:

```
int B[4][3];
int i;        //ranges from 0-3
```

My question is what types are the following elements:

```
B+i      
*(B+i)
```

What confuses me is that when I run:

```
std::cout<<B;
std::cout<<*B;
```

The outputs are the same.
I would be glad if someone could clarify that.

Comment: You are investigating an unfortunate aspect of C++, inherited from C. C-style arrays have certain sugar from C that makes them slightly inconsistent.

Comment: `B` is the address pointing to the start of a 2D array; `*B` is the address pointing to the start of a 1D array, which happens to live at the very beginning of the 2D array `B`. That's why the address of `B` and `*B` is the same, which you see with your `std::cout` lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`B` decays to `int (*)[3]`. The rule here is that the leftmost extent is removed, and a `*` is added instead.

Thus, `B+i` is `int (*)[3]` too.

And thus, `*(B+i)` is `int [3]` (which decays to `int *`).

---

The fact that `B == *B` is not hard to explain. `B` is an address of the first subarray (aka address of `B[0]`) and `*B` is an address of the first element of that subarray (aka address of `B[0][0]`).

---

**Explanation on types:**

All multidimensional arrays in C/C++ are in fact nested 1D arrays.

Your `int B[4][3];` can be considered a `T B[4]`, where `T` is `int [3]`.

Then the decay happens as for normal 1D array: `T B[4]` becomes `T (*)`. Because `T` is `int [3]`, `T (*)` is `int (*)[3]`.